# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderSubview" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, macos

Trying to build a MacOS app using react native
android and ios apps works fine
but when I try to run the macOS app shows me this.

[image: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderSubview" was not found in the UIManager.]

Tried different solutions like deleting node modules clear cache et etc. Nothing helped.

Comment: did you get to find out how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same error. I tried installing different dependencies and packages which solved my issue.

First of all, I'd suggest 'Clean Build Folder' from XCode > Product.

Then run the following command to install the required packages,

> npm i @react-navigation/native

"React Navigation is made up of some core utilities and those are then used by navigators to create the navigation structure in your app." - [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/)

> npm i @react-native-community/masked-view react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-safe-area-context

"This will install versions of these libraries that are compatible." - [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/)

For a Mac user who is developing for iOS needs to install the **pods**:

> npx pod-install ios

Try to build and run the app. Hope it will fix the problem.